# Telerik Report with Stored Procedure with multiple parameters not showing result

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, reporting-services, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am using telerik reports for my mvc project. I have designed costings report which gets data from stored procedure. this SP has 4-5 parameters. when i configure datasource for the report it asks for values for all parameters of stored procedure and in telerik report designer by providing values for the parameters it displays report perfectly.

i have added this report to my project. in my project when user selects costings as report to run, one popup form gets open where there are multiple combo boxes from where user can select values such as Branch, Costings Type, Client, Site etc. which are passed to the report as parameters. when i run the report from program it doesn't display the result. if i provide the same selected values to SP by executing it from SQL Server and it displayed the result properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but to me it seems like you report is not getting the params. Open your report in any xml editor (notepad++ will do the job) and check these sections:

```
<DataSources>
<SqlDataSource ConnectionString="hardcoded_or_from_your_webconfig" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="dbo.YourStoredProcedureName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" Name="AnydescriptiveNameforyoursource">
  <Parameters>
    <SqlDataSourceParameter DbType="Int32" Name="@Param1">
      <Value>
        <String>= Parameters.IncludeInactive.Value</String>
      </Value>
    </SqlDataSourceParameter>
    <SqlDataSourceParameter DbType="Int32" Name="@Param2">
      <Value>
        <String>= Parameters.YOURPARAMETER.Value</String>
      </Value>
    </SqlDataSourceParameter>
  </Parameters>
</SqlDataSource>
```

save your report and test.